# I cant display each item in a map with a delay

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to map my object of data in a slide and it is showing the data as "object object" when returned in a div.

When I take it out the div and put it with curly brackets, it displays all the data. How do I get it to display? Maybe I am formatting it in the wrong way. Maybe I was overlooking somethings.

```
import "../assets/Main.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { sliderData } from "../components/sliderData";
import  { useState, useEffect } from "react";


export default function Main({ slides }) {
const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0)
const length = slides.length;
const delay = 2500;

useEffect(() =>{
  setTimeout(
    () => 
    setCurrent((current) =>
    current === length -1 ? 0: current +1),
    delay
  )
},[current]);

const nextslide = () => {
setCurrent(current === length - 1 ? 0 : current +1)

  
}

if(!Array.isArray(slides) || slides.length <= 0) {
  return null; 
}


console.log(current)


return (
    <div className="main-container">
      <div className="main-info">Otis Guess: Sofware Engineer</div>
      <div className="info" 
      >{`About Me: ${sliderData.map((slide,index)=>{
         
         return(
           <div key = {index}>            
            {index === current &&(`${slide.info}`)}
           </div>
         ) 
       
         
        
      })}`}</div>
      <div className="instructions">Discover My Work</div>
      <Link to="/portfolio">
        <div className="main-oval">click here</div>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}



 export const sliderData = [
    {
        info: "Football Enthusiast"
    },
    {
        info: "Community Oriented"
    },
    {
        info: "Success Drivin"
    },
    {
        info: "Advid Gamer"
    }
]
```

Comment: I can see serveral issues: 
1) You return a string literal which is a string. So you cant have a div inside of that, which is why you see "Object object".
2) You could easily get your slide by doing slides[current] instead of iterating over all of them.
3) Consider initializing an interval at component first render, which you can easily cleanup on destruction. Cheers

Comment: do you have any examples of what this would look like, still new on the terminology.

Comment: I am trying to make it say about me then itterrate through the data to show the things about me as a slide here is the data. I added it above.

Comment: Sure: https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-water-9qevc

Comment: thanks alot, that was perfect example. I see what you did with the logic there.

Comment: can i use typescript on vs code?

Answer (score 1):

Well, your slide.info is an object, which is why it's returning Object object. If you'd like, you can console.log it first to see why it's doing that, or just run

```
${sliderData.map((slide,index)=>{
     return(
       <div key = {index}>            
        {index === current &&(`${JSON.parse(slide.info)}`)}
       </div>
     )         
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a good approach is to use **CSS Transitions** ( https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp ) with **transition-delay** property (https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay) applying to 'style' for each mapped component.

You can hide elements using opacity, as for example:

```css
div {
    transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
    transition-delay: 2500ms # you can calculate accordingly your needs
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div.active {
    opacity: 1;
    height: auto;
}
```